# am I backdoored?

Tags: wireless

I live with my roomate.. we share the same Wi-fi. WPA

I don't know much about where is the router or which contracts does we have.

I have Ubuntu 18.

I start notice some strange things: the wi-fi somentimes disconnects itself and ubuntu asks me to connect to the net, but when I do (this doesn't happen frequently it happned just two times) I can see that has been added some digits to the password in the wi-fi in order to make it disconnect

For example let's assume the passord is ''ttutidnsm'' ok?

Then I see that someone has changed adding some caracthers , so from ''ttutidnsm'' ---> it turns to ''ttutidnsm--uyir''

This disconnects the wi-fi and everytime I have to go to wi-fi center and cancel the adding caracthers and click ''connect'' to have again the connection.

My question is: Could it be a malware on my PC that wants to get the password of the wi-fi to go into the router to get the other PC, making me disconnecting and reconnecting it in order to capture the handshake?

My Pc connects automatically to wi-fi, I don't imput password everytime

I visited some naughty websites.

with adobe flash, and ubuntu is not updated to the last version, but to the the previous version (2018)

The question is: could be a malware trying to get the hanshake to go into the router and to reach the other PCs in the WLAN?

The other PC are not connected to mine.. we are inividual pcs going on internet under the same wi-fi router

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you have malware, that's not something you usually see with Linux. To me it sounds more like someone is doing a man in the middle attack using aircrack or some similar utility. Or, it could just be a Denial of Service attack using the same tool.

If it's a man in the middle attack, you will sometimes notice that the websites you are visiting are no longer secure - in the url you will see `http://` instead of `https://`

When you go to log into the router, did you notice it if it still secured by wpa? if it is not you would no longer see the icon that looks like a lock next to its name. This is an indication that someone is logged into your network and is spoofing the wireless access point so that it can intercept your traffic.

If you want to be sure - you can install a small utility that will change the mac address of your interface called `maccchanger` the command for a typical interface would be something like `macchanger -r wlan0`, which would change the mac address of your wireless card - once you do that you can try to log on again and see if you able to do so easily. Having said that, your attacker will soon realize that you have changed the address and can easily attack you via the new number.

PS: I wanted to put this into a comment instead of an answer but my rep is not high enough.